# Why was orbital bombardment not a common action during the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

During the entire length of the Clone Wars TV series, I do not recall orbital bombardment ever being used as a strategy to help soften enemy defenses prior to attack.

I get that in some cases, bombarding the planet from orbit would devastate the native population (like the campaigns on Ryloth). But specifically episodes like "Landing at Point Rain" in which the Grand Army of the Republic tried to retake the hostile world of Geonosis, why did the fleet not bombard the planet to eliminate most of the defenses prior to landing troops?

Comment: Possibly because the characters were not yet turned evil and cruel by years of war?

Answer (score 9):

According to the narrator of *The Clone Wars,* the droid factories of Geonosis were protected by ray-shields.

> On Geonosis, Separatist leader Poggle the Lesser, safe in his newly ray-shielded factories, creates thousands of terrible new weapons which march off the assembly line against the outnumbered clone army. ("Landing at Point Rain")

It's likely the Seperatists used similar technology on other planets.

On Ryloth, the Seperatists used the native Twi'leks as "living shields"

> I am utilizing the prisoners from this village as living shields. I calculate the Jedi will not risk the prisoners' safety with a direct assault. ("Innocents of Ryloth")

As many battles of the Clone Was occurred in occupied areas, the Republic would be hesitant to bomb them, both for moral and economic reasons.

Comment: So i get than the factory itself was ray shielded, seems a lot of the targets where outside the factory and the shield?  Why couldn't they bombard the targets outside the shield to make the landing easier?

Comment: @psubsee2003 You can see [here](https://youtu.be/Ed9F4qSp0lA) that the shield extends some distance from the factory, covering most of the Geonosis forces.

Comment: I have to go re-watch the episode entirely but i seem to recall the initial (and worst) of the battle occuring outside of the shield,  It wasn't until after Anakin, Obi-Wan, and Ki-Adi-Mundi had finally met at the staging area did someone need to go inside the shielded area to destroy it so they could land troops near the factory